# Create custom SharePoint workflow using SharePoint workflow foundation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

How to create a custom sharepoint workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is very generic, I can only provide a very generic answer. As such have a look at this introductory [MSDN article about getting started with workflows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj163917.aspx).

There are several ways to succeed - the two most used might be using Visual Studio and developing a custom solution and on the other hand SharePoint Designer - the (more or less) graphical and intuitive tool to manage your SharePoint UI.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are trying to do.  You can build workflows that can do anything in .Net using Windows Workflow Foundation (WF3) but it takes a bit of learning to be productive.  SharePoint Designer (SPD) workflows can do a few things e.g. send email, create tasks, etc. but I find you run up to limitations pretty quickly.  It's difficult to move SPD workflows from DEV to TEST to PROD and you end spending a ton of time implementing workarounds for things like string manipulation etc.  WF3 workflows must be deployed to your server as a WSP so it's a non-starter if your environment is locked down whereas SPD workflows are declarative and saved as Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML) and do not need to be deployed by and administrator.  If you have the money and you plan to create a lot of workflows you should look at Nintex which is the best of both worlds but only makes sense if you have more than 20 or so workflows.